# Sourcebuffer.appendBuffer throws InvalidState exception on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angular, buffer

I am trying to visualize in an HTML5 video element a stream of frames I receive from a server. I have implemented it using a sourceBuffer according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer)

The streaming works perfectly on Desktop (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) and on Android but on iOS the system throws an "InvalidState exception - Object is not in a valid state" each time I try to append a new frame to the buffer.

I have read around this can be a mimetype codec problem but even trying many of them it still does not work

I have tried using different codecs according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120717/h-264-video-wont-play-on-ios)

```
mimeCodec= 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001F"
```

I have also checked that system/OS supports the used codec by adding this check but it always returns true:

```
if (!('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec))) {
   reject('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ' + mimeCodec);
}
```